# Having trouble with split() function in r

Tags: r

I'm somewhat new to r and keep trying to split a dataframe into a list of dfs using the split() function in r as follows:

```
paylist <- split(payload, payload$officialDate)
```

and keep getting the error on occasion (though sometimes it works)

```
    Error in `vectbl_as_col_location()`:
! Can't subset columns past the end.
ℹ Location 95 doesn't exist.
ℹ There are only 3 columns.
```

This is the backtrace that comes up:

```
  Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─... %>% split(.$officialDate, drop = TRUE)
  2. ├─base::split(., .$officialDate, drop = TRUE)
  3. └─data.table:::split.data.table(., .$officialDate, drop = TRUE)
  4.   └─base::lapply(...)
  5.     └─data.table FUN(X[[i]], ...)
  6.       ├─x[ind]
  7.       └─tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(x, ind)
  8.         └─tibble:::vectbl_as_col_location(...)
  9.           ├─tibble:::subclass_col_index_errors(...)
 10.           │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 11.           └─vctrs::vec_as_location(j, n, names)
 12.             └─vctrs `<fn>`()
 13.               └─vctrs:::stop_subscript_oob(...)
 14.                 └─vctrs:::stop_subscript(...)
 15.                   └─rlang::abort(...)
```

This is what my dataframe looks like:

[image: This is what the df looks like]

Comment: If you try `split(as.data.frame(payload), payload$officialDate)` do you still get the error?

Comment: Ah that solved it. Thank you so much!